# How to fetch data Array inner array from JSON?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

I need a loop "activity_periods" of "start_time".

I am getting an error when I fetch the data from JSON. It is a React platform.

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "members": [{
    "id": "1",
    "real_name": "Demo1",
    "tz": "New York",
    "activity_periods": [
      {
        "start_time": "Feb 1 2020  1:33PM",
        "end_time": "Feb 1 2020 1:54PM"
      },
      {
        "start_time": "Mar 1 2020  11:11AM",
        "end_time": "Mar 1 2020 2:00PM"
      },
      {
        "start_time": "Mar 16 2020  5:33PM",
        "end_time": "Mar 16 2020 8:02PM"
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you provide more details of what you are trying to accomplish and what error you're seeing. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to loop and the issues you're seeing when "loading the json"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to loop over your data by mapping `data.members[0].activity_periods`.

I made a sandbox for you to test [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-wildflower-2lj7b)